# HTTPS to HTTP SAML SSO using mod_auth_mellon

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, https, httpd.conf, single-sign-on

I have a simple HTTPS to HTTP reverse proxy using Apache HTTPD (CentOS)

I have enabled mod_auth_mellon for SAML SSO, it works fine if I have a simple http proxy without any virtual host.

When I enable HTTPS & Virtual host, mellon auth is not working. In first place, its not taking me to the Okta login page.

I can see that HTTPS -> Http works fine without SAML SSO, its just not working if I enable SAML.

HTTPD Config:

```
<VirtualHost example.test.io:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://example.test.io:443
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example.test.io:443>

    ServerName example.test.io

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
    #ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule ^/content/([^/]+)/(.*) /repository/$2 [R=301,L]

    MellonCacheSize 100
    MellonLockFile "/run/mod_auth_mellon/lock"
    MellonPostTTL 900
    MellonPostSize 1048576
    MellonPostCount 100

    <Location />
        Require valid-user
        AuthType "Mellon"
        MellonVariable "cookie"
        MellonSecureCookie On
        MellonCookiePath /
        MellonUser "NAME_ID"
        MellonProbeDiscoveryTimeout 30
        #MellonDiscoveryURL

        MellonEnable "auth"
        MellonEndpointPath "/sso"
        MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/httpd/mellon/https__okta.key
        MellonSPCertFile /etc/httpd/mellon/https__okta.cert
        MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/mellon/https__okta.xml
        MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/mellon/https-idp-metadata.xml

        #RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic xxx"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
        ProxyPass http://app.com:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse http://app.com:8081/
    </Location>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app_access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

I guess its going to a wrong app url location, then it throws 404 error.

Thoughts ?